# Rails not possible dynamic add another input field in nested form (two level) association has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working in Rails, and I have a problem in formular

### Formular

[image]

### Models

I have 3 models probably with wrong association

```
class TagCondition < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tag_percents
  has_many :tags, through: :tag_percents
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag_percents
end

class TagPercent < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tag_condition, optional: true
  belongs_to :tag, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :tag_percent, dependent: :destroy
end
```

---

### Controller

```
class TagConditionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tag_condition, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @tag_condition = TagCondition.new
    per = @tag_condition.tag_percents.build
    per.build_tag (maybe wrong, but "per.tags.build" get error)
  end

  def tag_condition_params
      params.require(:tag_condition).permit(
        :condition,
        tag_percents_attributes: [ :id, :percent, 
        {tag_attributes: [ :id, :name]}] )
    end
```

### View

```
<%= form_for(tag_condition) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :condition %>
    <%= f.text_field :condition %>
  </div>

...
  <tbody class="fields">
     <%= f.fields_for :tag_percents do |builder| %>
       <%= render 'tag_percent_fields' , :f => builder %>
     <% end %>
  </tbody>
...

and in partial _tag_percent...
  <td>
    <%= f.fields_for **:tag** do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    <% end %>
  </td>

  <td>
      <%= f.number_field :percent, in: 1..100, placeholder: 100, class: "form-control" %>
  </td>
```

When I change in partial from `":tag"` to `":tags"`, it works in formular, but unfortunately I have a problem with save records to database ... `INSERT INTO table` TAGS is missing, I have only `INSERTS to tag_percent` and `ta_conditions`

Can you help me please? Or show some tutorial (or a simple project on Github) with same case (everything in Youtube is only with one level nested form no my case **has many through with field percent in "middle" table Tag_percent** and dynamic add rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
With help this demo project
https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo